# Please help me finding $DB$ in this diagram

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

[image: myshape]

*diagram 1* is what the question has given me, and I've totalized it in *diagram 2*. Actually Diagram 2 is what i think must be the full diagram of this problem.

First of all the puzzle says:
In the triangle $\triangle ABC$, bisector of smallest external angle, crosses the line &BC&(the largest line) in the point &D&.
Now it says to find:$$\frac{S_\triangle ABD}{S_\triangle ABC}=?$$
So draw a complete diagram namely "diagram 2". Actually I draw a parallel line to $AB$, named $MD$.
And also I streched the line $CA$ to $CM$. $M$ was named the cross point of the lines $DM$ and $CM$.

So now we have Thales's theorem in $\triangle CMD$.

I think that $\triangle ABC \thicksim \triangle AMD$. Because $\angle MAD=\angle DAB$.

And I Also know if we draw the height $AH$ in $\triangle ABC$ then:
$$\frac{S_\triangle ABD}{S_\triangle ABC}=\frac{DB}{BC}$$
Now how to find $$DB=?$$

Comment: Can you use trigonometry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your drawing is not perfect so you are missing some obvious things:

You are right, triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle MDC$ are similar because all their angles are equal. It means that:

$$\frac{MD}{AB}=\frac{MC}{AC}=\frac{MA+AC}{AC}\tag{1}$$

On the other side, triangle $\triangle MAD$ is isosceles because $\angle MDA=\angle DAB$ (as angles with parallel legs) and $\angle DAB=\angle DAM$. Because of that: $MD=MA=x$. Put it all now in (1) and you get:

$$\frac{x}{3}=\frac{x+5}{5}$$

$$x=\frac72$$

On the other side (Thales theorem):

$$\frac{DB}{BC}=\frac{MA}{AC}=\frac{\frac72}{5}=\frac7{10}=\frac{S_\triangle ABD}{S_\triangle ABC}$$

Comment: Thanks Oldboy! I know my diagram is not really accurate, but actually it is based on what our teacher gave us! Actually our teacher draw it!